# Update existing app on appstore with different codebase and project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

Our company have an existing app on App Store. It is developed using React Native. Right now, we re-develop the app using Swift. So over all we have 2 different Apps/projects. It is possible that we can override the existing react native app on App Store? so we can upload the swift app without creating a new listing? If it is possible can you please point me to the right instruction or direction. I am getting confused with a lot of answers and article. Also is it possible to change the media banner on App Store connect? right now I didnt see any options on how to change it. Thank you guys!

Comment: Yes, you can update your existing app without any problems. You just need proper certificates and a profile to upload the app to the App store connect. Create a new App version in AppStore -> iOS App section clicking on + icon. Update your app information and submit to the store. ref: https://www.swing2app.com/blog/how-to-submit-your-app-to-the-app-store-in-2022/

Comment: Exactly; as long as the exported binary has the exact same bundle ID, even a full rewrite should be OK.

Comment: Maybe you need to migrate your core data before uploading the app to AppStore.

Comment: I know this kind of late, but thank you so much for you all answering my question